# Solutions of $p!q! = r!$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

The title says it all, more or less. Obviously, there are infinitely many "trivial" integral solutions of the form $p=n, q=(n!-1), r= n!$. How many non-trivial solutions are there?

I came across this about ten years ago; as far as I can tell, it hasn't appeared here before, so I thought that it might be of interest. I'm actually most interested in finding whether there was any progress made since [Florian Luca's 2007 article.](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1450772)

Comment: (It's weird that Luca's extract at the beginning calls this a Diophantine equation.  That's not any meaning of "Diophantine" than any I've seen.)

Comment: For what it's worth, if $p \leq q < r$ then there obviously cannot be any primes in $\{q+1, \ldots, r\}$. So $q$ has to be 'close' to $r$.

Comment: I think $6!7!=10!$ is the only known nontrivial solution, and it's conjectured that there aren't any others.

Comment: @TMM Right. That's why it's likely that there will only be a finite number of nontrivial solutions (the first one, actually, is fairly small). Also, I agree that MO would be an appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it is not uncommon for number theorists to refer to just about any old equation as a Diophantine equation, if their interest lies in integral solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only citation of the Luca paper found by MathSciNet:

> Bhat, K. G.; Ramachandra, K.:
> A remark on factorials that are products of factorials. (Russian. Russian summary) Mat. Zametki 88 (2010), no. 3, 350–354; translation in
> [Math. Notes 88 (2010), no. 3–4, 317–320](https://doi.org/10.1134/S0001434610090038)