# How to find other nontrivial solutions of $a!b!=c!$?

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I know only one nontrivial solution of this equation: $6!\cdot 7!=10!$. There is also a series of trivial solutions: $n!(n!-1)!=(n!)!,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. So my question is how to find any other solutions of the equation

$$a!b!=c!,\ a, b, c\in\mathbb{N}\quad(1)$$

I'm also interested in the solutions of more complex equations:

$$\prod\limits_{a\in A}a!=b!,\ A\subset\mathbb{N}\quad(2)$$

$$\prod\limits_{a\in A}a!=\prod\limits_{b\in B}b!,\ A,B\subset\mathbb{N},\ A\cap B=\varnothing\quad(3)$$

**Update:** as it is noted in comments both (1) and (2) equations have already appeared here. So the main question now is **whether anything is known about equation (3)**.

Comment: @MJD Thank you! What about the 3rd equation? I can't find anything about it in your reference...

Comment: @MJD: If it does, it doesn't address it directly (so far as I can tell).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: [Also relevant: Solutions of $p!q!=r!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150192/solutions-of-pq-r)

Comment: @MJD Thank you again. As I understand there is a good overview of the problem (2) in the book of Richard Guy but he says nothing about (3).