# Integer solutions of $\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b) = \Gamma(c)$

Tags: number-theory, gamma-function

> Are there infinitely many nontrivial integer solutions $(a,b,c)$ of
>
> $$\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)=\Gamma(c)\hspace{10mm}?$$

This seems like it may have been asked before but I didn't find an earlier question (yet). I checked for about $c < 200$ and $b-a < 10$ and found only $(a,b,c)=(4,6,7),(7,8,11).$

Comment: If $a, b, c$ must be integers then are you just asking about factorials?

Comment: @badjohn it came up in context of gamma but yes.

Comment: So, we can assume that $a < b < c$.  Consider the prime factorisation of both sides.  If there is a prime $p$ between $b$ and $c$ then it will be factor of the RHS but not the LHS.  This will place severe limits on possible solutions.

Comment: @badjohn: So must be $\pi(b) = \pi(c)$?

Comment: If you are only asking about factorials, this may be what you're looking for : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112670/on-the-factorial-equations-a-b-c-and-abc-d

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150192/solutions-of-pq-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I would expect so.  There is the well known example $10!=7!×6!$ but this satisfies that restriction.

Comment: @daniel I don't really care about the reputation, but I think it is good to leave this one around. Other people might also be looking for the gamma variant of this factorial equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $(d+1, d! , d!+1)$ is a solution for all $d$:

$$\Gamma(d+1)\Gamma(d!) = d!(d!-1)! = (d!)! = \Gamma(d!+1)$$

However, this might be considered as a trivial solution. But since you included $(4,6,7)$, which is this solution with $d=3$, I thought it was worth pointing out.

I think the really trivial solutions are $(1,d,d)$ and $(2,d,d)$.

---

A bit more advanced stuff: Under the abc conjecture, there are only finitely many other solutions than those I mentioned above. Probably, the only one is $(7,8,11)$, which corresponds with $6!7!=10!$.  See also: [Solutions of $p!q! = r!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150192/solutions-of-pq-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)